# Reverse engineer bitwise operations

Tags: math, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to reverse engineer a BlueTooth device. There's a lookup table that looks like this:

| bit | error. |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | error code 1 |
| 1 | error code 2 |
| 2 | error code 3 |
| 3 | error code 4 |
| 4 | error code 5 |
| 5 | error code 6 |
| 6 | error code 7 |
| 7 | error code 8 |
| 8 | error code 9 |
| 9 | error code 10 |
| 10 | error code 11 |
| 11 | error code 12 |
| 12 | error code 13 |
| 13 | error code 14 |
| 14 | error code 15 |
| 15 | error code 16 |

I managed to get 128 from the bluetooth device and I know it equals to 15 (error code 16).
I also managed to get 512 from the device and I know it quals to 1 in the table (error code 2)

How do I figure out what bitwise operation I'm supposed to do to turn 128 to 15 and 512 to 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your bytes are in the wrong order

Comment: if I reverse the bytes I get 32768 for bit 15 (error code 16). Does it make more sense now?

Comment: The index of the set bit is the error code. That typically mean that's a bunch of flags of which more than one could be set at the same time

Comment: Oh yeah, so 32768 is 1000000000000000 which means if bit number 15 is 1 that error shows.